# VF Page: Best way to avoid datepicker focus on load?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have two date fields on my Visualforce page and on occasions the datepicker/calendar pops up upon page load. I understand one way to prevent this is to use javascript as suggested below:

```
<input id="hiddenElementId" type="hidden" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = setFocus
function setFocus()
{
         document.getElementById("hiddenElementId").focus();
}
</script>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000094kJIAQ

However this post is pretty old now, is this still considered the best way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please include the snippet below after the page tag.

```
<apex:page>
    <script>function setFocusOnLoad() {}</script>
    <!-- further content -->
</apex:page>
```

Hope this will work for you.