# Can you set a visualforce apex attribute dynamically using javascript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to dynamically set the `showDatePicker`attribute of an apex input field to get around a strange bug I've been experiencing. I've tried setting attributes using `document.getElementbyID('{!component.id}').label="new label"` and nothing seems to change even though the method is called. Do I need to rerender the input field or the panel that it's in for attribute changes to take effect or are they unchangeable after the window loads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VF Page: Best way to avoid datepicker focus on load?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51941/vf-page-best-way-to-avoid-datepicker-focus-on-load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showDatePicker` is a custom salesforce attribute. So if you want to change it on the page, you will have to assign it with a boolean property value in controller and rerender.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!object.DateField__c}" showDatePicker="{!booleanProperty}" id="fieldId"/>
```

Also as per salesforce documentation, it works only in some type of fields,

> This attribute only affects date and datetime fields, and activating a
>   browser-based type-appropriate selection widget requires the type
>   attribute be set to one of these date- or time-compatible types:
>
> - date datetime datetime-local month week time

Label will be a rendering as a different label tag associated with the field. So if you use select field using javascript and change label, it will not change actual label of the field. Use inspect element/browser console to find rendered HTML elements and select accordingly