# Annoying "jumps" to visualforce page that is located on page layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have added a visualforce page to one of our case's page layouts.
The Visualforce page has an input field and that's it, you insert the input yourself and hit save.

Users in my org are complaining that every time they view a case, it 'jumps' to the section of the visualforce page. it's like the VF page's input has autofocus attribute or something.

Can someone provide a solution for this?

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="CreateRelatedAppsInCaseExtension">
    <apex:form id="rerenderForm" rendered="true">
        <apex:messages />
        <apex:inputText value="{! searchBy }" style="float:left;" styleClass="searchBy" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}" reRender="rerenderForm"></apex:commandButton>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Sounds like the same problem as here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51941/vf-page-best-way-to-avoid-datepicker-focus-on-load

Comment: Good :) Voting to close as a duplicate then.